# Maven Surefire Plugin version confusion

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-surefire-plugin

I added the plugin like so:

```xml
    <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.surefire.version>

    [...]

     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <parallel>methods</parallel>
          <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

… and all went well.

I changed the version to 2.22.2 and got the error: `Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2' not found`.

However, when I do an artifact search from within IntelliJ, it does find that version. Okay, I revert the change back to the original version I had.

Now, when I ran `mvn test` the following caught my eye:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ regression-tests ---
```

Why isn't 3.0.0-M5 used? Where does 2.12.4 come from? I did a search in my pom.xml on 'surefire', but no other hits appear other than what I've shown above.

Looking through IntelliJ's Preferences, I've found the repo that's being used is https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/, and all versions mentioned are there.

Could someone explain to me what is going on? Why can't it find 2.22.2? Why does it show 2.12.4 is used while 3.0.0-M5 is in pom.xml?

For completeness' sake, here's my mvn:

```
❯ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.2 (ea98e05a04480131370aa0c110b8c54cf726c06f)
Maven home: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.2/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_292, vendor: Azul Systems, Inc., runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "11.5.2", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Okay, I revert the change back to the original version I had.

Invoke **Reload** action in Maven tool window after you change the pom.xml file.

You can see the plugin version which is used in Maven tool window:

[image]

You can also use **Show Effective POM** action in IDE to see all the actual dependencies, plugins and their versions which are used in this Maven project:
[image]

Comment: In the Maven Tool Window, it said 2.12.4. So, nothing new there. Show Effective POM was new to me, and it still showed me 2.12.4. However, I noted that the whole plugin section for Surefire 2.22.2 was gone. So, because of that, I've found the problem. This pom file uses Profiles and Surefire was only listed in one of the Profiles. So when that Profile isn't active, it effectively (pun intended) meant Maven loaded whatever it wanted. So I copied the plugin over to the other Profiles and now it works. Thank you.